# Sorting and taking highest values from a file

Tags: python

I have a file where the lines look like this:

tom, 10, 20, 0, 100, 0, 100, 70, 80, 90, 0, 80, 85

I want to take the number 10 through the second 100, and use the greatest four values. Then take the average.

I have:

```
        for i in range((my_dictionary[1:6])) :
              for item in inlist:
                  if item > largest:
                      largest = item
                  elif largest > item > second_largest:
                      second_largest = item
                  elif largest > item > second_largest > third_largest:
                      third_largest = item
                  elif largest > item > second_largest > third_largest > fourth_largest:
                      fourth_largest = item
        q = (sum(inlist))/4
```

This does not work. I am concerned that each line is not considered a list. The error appears on first line as type is unhashable.

Edit: I want to do this without modules. Also, I am creating a list for the line with : name, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, a1, a2, a3, a4, midterm, final = line.strip().split(',')

Comment: Please copy the entire output here, verbatim. Never try to paraphrase error messages, as you'll generally omit some critical information, and it makes the question is less googleable.

Comment: You also need to add the code that gets lines; the error is clearly a problem with `my_dictionary[1:6]` (you can't slice a `dict`), so I'm thinking you created some more complicated data structure than just a split line. Also, `range(my_dictionary[1:6])` makes no sense at all; `range` generates sequential integers, and you passed it a slice instead of an end point. You probably just want to iterate the slice directly, no use of `range` at all.

Answer (score 2):

No need for complicated conditionals, just use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) or since it's a small number of items anyway, sort the lot of 'em and slice off the largest:

Your code contains insufficient context to figure out where `my_dictionary` came from, but the general idea would be to slice off the values you care about to make a `list` to sort, then average those:

```
import heapq

top4 = sorted(myvalues[1:7], reverse=True)[:4]
# or heapq
top4 = heapq.nlargest(4, myvalues[1:7])
```

then average them:

```
avg = sum(top4) / 4.
```

Comment: I am looking to solve this without using modules. Any ideas? The other response does not work.

Comment: `sorted` requires no special modules. `heapq.nlargest` is just an optimization for when the number of items to pick is small, and the set to pick from is large; in your case, `sorted` works fine, but it sounds like you forgot to convert the input values from `str` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Edited: Here's a complete example, in Python 3. Note I added `reversed=True` on `sorted()` call. That was a bug earlier.

Also, please note that there are no "modules" here. These are all functions/keywords/capabilities built in to the base python. No imports required!

```
input = 'tom, 10, 20, 0, 100, 0, 100, 70, 80, 90, 0, 80, 85'
my_dictionary = input.split(', ')
username = my_dictionary.pop(0)
my_dictionary = list(map(int, my_dictionary))


greatest_4values = sorted(my_dictionary[0:6], reverse=True)[0:4]
average = sum(greatest_4values)/4.0


print("Average = ", average)
print("Greatest 4 values = ", greatest_4values)
```

Comment: This leads to an error that I cannot perform an operation on the values in the range. unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' Full message is: Error in evaluating function:
TypeError at line 16
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: That probably means you still have a list full of strings, not numbers. See the last line in the first paragraph of my sample code, where I `map(int,` the list to convert from strings (like `'100'`) to numbers (like `100`). (Note the missing quotes.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume we're starting like this:

```
my_dictionary = 'tom', 10, 20, 0, 100, 0, 100, 70, 80, 90, 0, 80, 85
```

And we only want the numbers from 10 to the second 100, so...

```
aList = my_dictionary[1:7]
```

Python's built-in `sorted` will order the numbers from smallest to largest,

```
aList = sorted(aList)
```

Since we want the four **largest** numbers in a list that is ordered from smallest to largest, we want the **last** four items in the list.

```
greatest = aList[-4:]
```

Finally, to get the average, we can simply `sum` the values in the greatest list and divide by 4 (since we are averaging a total of 4 values).

```
average = float(sum(greatest) / 4)
```

`float` will just let the answer have decimal places. Without `float`, the average is 57. With `float`, the average is 57.5